# How to Stream and Send a File to Telegram Using python-telegram-bot in Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm working on a Python project where I need to download a file from a remote location and then send it to a Telegram chat using the python-telegram-bot library. However, I want to avoid waiting for the entire file to download before sending it to Telegram. Instead, I'd like to stream the file as it downloads. How can I achieve this using python-telegram-bot? Specifically, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to send chunks of the file to Telegram while it's still being downloaded, rather than waiting for the entire file to be downloaded before sending. Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests